# Get the detail informations from a .png file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, png

How can I get the detail informations from a specific .png file in PowerShell?
Like dimensions, bit depth and size.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get most of this information from the files extended properties like this:

```
$path = 'D:\image.png'
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$folder = Split-Path $path
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)

$width = 27
$height = 28
$Dimensions = 26
$size = 1

$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $width)
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $height)
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $Dimensions)
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $size)
```

You can also get the size in other ways such as `(Get-Item D:\image.png).Length / 1KB`.

The bit depth property doesn't seem to be listed in the extended properties though even though its available when you right click the file.

*Update* Another option is to use .NET proper to avoid using COM:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$png = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap 'D:\image.png'
$png.Height
$png.Width
$png.PhysicalDimension
$png.HorizontalResolution
$png.VerticalResolution
```

*Update 2* The PixelFormat property gives you the bit depth.

```
$png.PixelFormat
```

The property is an enumeration of possible formats. You can view the complete list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat).

For example, `Format32bppArgb` is defined as

> Specifies that the format is 32 bits per pixel; 8 bits each are used
> for the alpha, red, green, and blue components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally choose to use Wia.ImageFile. with which I can get more simply some infomations (like bit depth).

Comment: @Etienne I added another option. You can use .NET and avoid using COM.

Comment: Thank you for your last update. I am a beginner in PowerShell, so if I understand it's best to use .NET instead of COM? With Wia.ImageFile I also found IsIndexedPixelFormat, IsAlphaPixelFormat, IsExtendedPixelFormat and IsAnimated, which are interesting for my needs. I have not managed to find them with the System.Drawing. Thank you very much for your answer, this is very appreciated. Etienne.

Comment: @Etienne You can use COM however some COM objects are installed with specific applications and some are only available in specific versions of Windows so you have to watch out for those when you  distribute you script.

Comment: Nicely done. Note that the [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Drawing.Bitmap) approach entails loading the entire image into memory (calling `$png.Dispose()` after use is advisable). On the plus side, it supports _multiple_ formats: `.bmp`, `.gif`, `.exif`, `.jpg`, `.png`, and `.tiff`, whereas the indices for the `Shell.Application` COM object's `.GetDetailsOf()` method appear to be (mostly) `.png`-specific.

Answer (score 5):

- You might want to use the [PowershellPack Module](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) which contains get-image:

  ```
  PS D:\> import-module psimagetools
  PS D:\> get-item .\fig410.png | get-image
  FullName              : D:\fig410.png
  FormatID              : {B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}
  FileExtension         : png
  FileData              : System.__ComObject
  ARGBData              : System.__ComObject
  Height                : 450
  Width                 : 700
  HorizontalResolution  : 96,0119934082031
  VerticalResolution    : 96,0119934082031
  PixelDepth            : 32
  IsIndexedPixelFormat  : False
  IsAlphaPixelFormat    : True
  IsExtendedPixelFormat : False
  IsAnimated            : False
  FrameCount            : 1
  ActiveFrame           : 1
  Properties            : System.__ComObject
  ```
- or you could use **Wia.ImageFile** directly (which is how the get-image function does it) this way:

  ```
  PS D:\> $image  = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile
  PS D:\> $image.loadfile("D:\fig410.png")
  PS D:\> $image

  FormatID              : {B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}
  FileExtension         : png
  FileData              : System.__ComObject
  ARGBData              : System.__ComObject
  Height                : 450
  Width                 : 700
  HorizontalResolution  : 96,0119934082031
  VerticalResolution    : 96,0119934082031
  PixelDepth            : 32
  IsIndexedPixelFormat  : False
  IsAlphaPixelFormat    : True
  IsExtendedPixelFormat : False
  IsAnimated            : False
  FrameCount            : 1
  ActiveFrame           : 1
  Properties            : System.__ComObject
  ```

Comment: Not found link, any alternatives ?

Comment: No official link, yet https://github.com/thlorenz/settings/tree/master/WindowsPowerShell/Modules might help

Answer (score 3):

The Scripting Guy wrote an article about getting files metadata based on Shell.Application https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/08/14/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-find-files-metadata/

Comment: Thanks for this article, very interesting. In my case I prefer to use the Wia.ImageFile, more simple for my needs.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Etienne ***Wia.ImageFile*** is _COM_

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use .net framework to load the image and then get the width:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\image.png')
$image.Width
```