# Powershell: Delete images of certain dimensions

Tags: image, powershell

I want to delete all *.jpg files in a specific folder and all its subfolders which have e.g. width unequal 800 and height unequal 600 (leaving only 800x600 jpg images).

Can someone tell me how to do this in Powershell?

I know I can remove *.jpg images with

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.jpg -Recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

But I can't seem to find how to select height/width of an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the detail informations from a .png file in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552367/get-the-detail-informations-from-a-png-file-in-powershell)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `System.Drawing.Image` .NET Object:

```
$(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg).FullName | ForEach-Object { 
    $img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_); 
    $dimensions = "$($img.Width) x $($img.Height)"

    If ($dimensions -eq "800 x 600") {
        Remove-Item $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it says FromFile "Path has an invalid format". Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You're probably not passing a valid path in the method. Check to make sure that file exists

Comment: I have used -Path '.\' in Get-ChildItem, but it didn't work. I also tried the absolute path, and I also tried it '.\*'. It always tells me the same error message.

Comment: @walidtoumi `$_` is already the `.FullName` as you can see from `$(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg).FullName` that was sent into the pipe

Comment: @user4132336 Get-Childitem will automatically output for the current directory. If you are looking for all subfolders and files consider using the `-Recurse` parameter