# How to delete a image in cmd depending on its properties?

Tags: windows, image, powershell, cmd

I don't have experiences with cmd script, but I want to do a little thing that is deleting images with different dimensions  **that aren't 1920x1080** in just one folder. Every image there with 1920 px of Width is definetely a 1920x1080 image. So I made this script:

```
(for /r %%F in (*) do (
    set "width="
    set "height="
    for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b in ('"%%Width%%:%%Height%%"') do (
        if %%~bF NEQ 1920 del "%%F"
    )
)
```

But it's outputing that the file sintax name is incorrect and the files are not being deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get more help if you add a powershell tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks @somebadhat, i'll do that!

Comment: Try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314980/powershell-delete-images-of-certain-dimensions) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314980/powershell-delete-images-of-certain-dimensions). If you get the solution working, you can post your own answer to the question too.

Comment: @vonPryz I'm actually using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855048/get-image-file-dimensions-in-bat-file) to guideline me. But I couldn't adapt the code as I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell you could load the file as a `System.Drawing.Image` object and get the width and height from there:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$imagesToDelete = Get-ChildItem . |Where-Object {
  try {
    $pic = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)
    # We only want images that are _not_ 1920px wide
    $pic.Width -ne 1920
  }
  catch{
    # Ignore errors (== probably not an image)
  }
  finally {
    # Clean up
    if($pic -is [IDisposable]){
      $pic.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
```

`$imagesToDelete` will then contain all image files with width different than `1920`, you can proceed to delete with `Remove-Item`:

```bsh
$imagesToDelete |Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias. I will wait for some answer in cmd cause I already have a piece of code before this "delete image" on cmd. If I can't make it, I will change to Powershell and use your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias! I changed my previous cmd script to Powershell and your code worked flawlessly.

Comment: @dsenese That's great to hear, you're most welcome! I'd strongly suggest leaving batch scripts behind and start to embrace PowerShell in general (it's installed on Windows by default for more than 10 years now!)