# "Out of memory" error when pulling metadata from picture files using Powershell

Tags: powershell

**Using Powershell, what I am trying to accomplish is:**

1. Loop through a directory of image files (with no file extensions, btw)
2. Extract height and width of each
3. Copy only image files that have particular attributes to another directory

**What I'm currently doing (irrelevant code excluded):**

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)
    $dimensions = "$($img.Width) x $($img.Height)"
    $size = $img.Length
    If ($dimensions -eq "1920 x 1080" -and $size -gt 100kb)
        {
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceDir\$img -Destination $destDir\$img.jpg > $null
        }
}
```

**The error I receive:**

```
Exception calling "FromFile" with "1" argument(s): "Out of memory."
At C:\blahblah
+     $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OutOfMemoryException
```

From what I've been researching, the error comes from loading a large image file in memory. I've read that streaming is the better way to go, but I haven't found a way to make this work and have little experience with it.

I have tried substituting the second line with:
`$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream([System.IO.MemoryStream]$_.FullName)`
but it barks at me saying Cannot convert the "C:\blahblah" value of type "System.String" to type "System.IO.MemoryStream"

Comment: Alternative approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552367/get-the-detail-informations-from-a-png-file-in-powershell

Comment: From the docs: If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an `OutOfMemoryException` exception. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Eris - well, that solves it doesn't it? You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to an answer:

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an `OutOfMemoryException` exception.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that streaming is the better way to go, but I haven't found a way to make this work and have little experience with it.

```
try {
  # create filestream from file
  $Stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $_.FullName,'Open'
  $Image  = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($Stream)
  $dimensions = "$($Image.Width) x $($Image.Height)"
  if($dimensions -eq '1920 x 1080' -and $_.Length -gt 100kb)
  {
    # Copy-Item
  }
}
finally {
  $Image,$Stream |ForEach-Object {
    # Clean up
    $_.Dispose()
  }
}
```

Comment: Exception calling "FromStream" with "1" argument(s): "Parameter is not valid."  
    At C:\blahblah  
    +         $image  = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($stream)  
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException  
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: I think this is because not all of the files it loops through are valid bitmaps. I wonder how I can filter these out.