# Figure out height and width of .jpg files

Tags: powershell

I have a series of .jpg images I cloned from an online repository, I also copied them with wget but now I need to insert them in an HTML file and I need to find out what their height and width are. I know the size but that doesn't help.
It's most likely a very basic command but I'm a beginner so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: On Linux it'd be `identify path/to/the.jpg`.

Comment: This should get you the answer you need. The answer provides multiple ways to get the height and width using PowerShell https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554165/3474677

Comment: @ChadBaldwin is correct - the linked duplicate should also work for `.jpg` files, using the [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Drawing.Bitmap) approach.